# Getting 'unterminated object at' when trying to get value of certain key from JSON

Tags: android, json, firebase, android-json

Here's the json structure:

```
{userModel={name=Mark Kohl Mundi, photo_profile=***}, message=hi, timeStamp=1510326004316, newMsgIndicator=0}
```

Here's what I'm trying:

```
for (DataSnapshot childrenSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    try {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(childrenSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        String a = reader.getString("newMsgIndicator");
        Log.d("A", String.valueOf(a));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 23 of {userModel={name=Mark Kohl Mundi, photo_profile=***}, message=hi, timeStamp=1510326004316, newMsgIndicator=0}
```

I know the error is because there is no double quotes (`""`) in the value of the keys.

What I  want to know how can I insert double quotes in the json I'm getting.

Comment: `name=Mark Kohl Mundi` should be `name="Mark Kohl Mundi"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `JSONObject` in order to get data from a Firebase database. Firebase database is structured as pair of key and value, which means that every node in the database is a `Map`. So instead of using JSONObject, i recomand you using this line of code:

```
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) childrenSnapshot.getValue();
```

Having this map, you can iterate now to get the data accordingly.

If your reference is pointing on a particular user object (node), to get the actual name, please use the following code:

```
String name = childrenSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
```